# AddRunningClient starting device on non-zero client count in iphone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

Can anyone tell me what this message means?

AddRunningClient starting device on non-zero client count.

Thank you.

Abbas.

Comment: More info pertaining to the context of the message?

Comment: -1; not enough detail here as to what's going on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this the AVAudioPlayer? and is it in the simulator. If it is, it is just a bug in the API and can be ignored. It should be fine on the device.